# How to fill two floats to precision of one of them?

Tags: javascript

I have two numbers, for example:

```
var a = $('input#number_1').val(); // 12;
var b = $('input#number_2').val(); // 0.01;
```

How to fill a to precision of b?

```
a: 12.01
b: 0.01
```

or fill both to for example:

```
a: 12.0000
b: 0.0100
```

Edit:

```
var a = parseFloat($('input#number_1').val()); // 12;
var b = parseFloat($('input#number_2').val()); // 0.01;
```

Comment: And you obviously do not know what I was thinking. very argumentative comment, congratulations.

Comment: It's not argumentative at all, in fact I was trying to help out by pointing out those are strings and that either you've made a mistake in the code, or it needs further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that in your code, `a` and `b` are **strings**, not numbers.

What you could do is convert them both to number, the do a simple `toString`, find out how many digits are after the `.` in each of them, and then use the larger of those numbers with `toFixed` on the numbers (which lets you say how many places after the decimal you want).

For example:

```js
var a = $('input#number_1').val();
var b = $('input#number_2').val();

// Convert them to numbers
var aValue = +a;
var bValue = +b;

// Find out which has more digits after the decimal
var maxDigits = 0;
var n;
a = String(aValue);
n = a.indexOf('.');
if (n !== -1) {
  maxDigits = a.length - n - 1;
}
b = String(bValue);
n = b.indexOf('.');
if (n !== -1) {
  maxDigits = Math.max(b.length - n - 1, maxDigits);
}

// Convert back to strings with that many of digits
a = aValue.toFixed(maxDigits);
b = bValue.toFixed(maxDigits);

// Put them back in the fields if that's what you want
$('input#number_1').val(a);
$('input#number_2').val(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="number_1" value="12">
<input id="number_2" value="0.01">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript toFixed function, which is used for fix decimal value . you can set number of decimal value to function. make sure what you are passing. you may change it as per your requirement,

```js
var num = 5;
var n = num.toFixed(2)
alert(n);
num = 5.6785;
n = num.toFixed(2)
alert(n);
```

Refrence: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp